How do you resolve merging conflicts in an install-state.gz file?
I'm trying to merge a new version release of a project I'm working on and used git rebase to do so.  One of the files that has conflicts is my .yarn/install-state.gz file.  However when I click on it my editor shows a warning on the page that says

The file is not displayed in the text editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.

I click the open anyway button and it shows a bunch of unintelligible characters. If I try to open it in the merge editor I get an error telling me it can't be opened.  How can I resolve the merging issues if this file is unreadable?

.gz files are compressed so trying to work on it in a editor sounds futile.... I wonder where that file comes from. Is it a product of the build?

Choose either one. As .gz is a binary format, if you want to merge its contents, you need to implement a merge driver. The driver instructs to extract the 2 gz files, merge the inside files and compress the result files. But I think it'll be a hard job. If you don't want to choose either side, you can manually extract, merge and compress.

This file should not be committed.

.yarn/install-state.gz is an optimization file that you shouldn't ever have to commit.

https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#which-files-should-be-gitignored
Resolve the conflict by

deleting the file from the index
git rm --cached .yarn/install-state.gz


adding it to your .gitignore for the future, along with the other yarn files mentioned in the FAQs.



That's what I wound up doing, except in my case I just reset the file in git and added it to my .gitignore file.

@Optiq: watch out for the following trap: "adding a line in .gitignore" is not the same as "removing the file from tracking". See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore. You can check locally if git ls-files still lists your .yarn/install-state.gz file.
